# convert user input date to mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

Iam new in `codeigniter`. I tried to convert a user input date with format `dd-mm-yyyy` to mysql format `yyyy-mm-dd`. But I got only the functions here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html.  Is there any way to do this? Please help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

php can do that, you don't need codeigniter helper

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('18-10-2014'));
```

Comment: You are right, just declare before a variable with date, and put the variable instead of '`18-10-2014'`